# Adding values to existing string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv, sql-update

This sounds like a basic stuff but I'm running our of caffeine and my brain is seizing...

I have a table with where couple columns are set as datatype = text and contain comma separated strings, something like this

```
id   |   labels                       | items
------------------------------------------------
123  |  Resources,Faculty Resources   | 2323,97
```

If I know row ID can I append new values to labels and items via UPDATE or do I first need to query the table, get data, append values and then do update with new string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single update query can do:

```
update mytable 
set items = concat(coalesce(concat(items, ','), ''), :new_item)
where id = :id
```

... where `:new_item` is the item you want to add and `:id` is the `id` of the target row.

The `coalesce()`/`concat()` logic takes in account the possibility that `items` could be `null` on an existing row. If that's never the case, then simply:

```
update mytable 
set items = concat(items, ',', :new_item)
where id = :id
```

Note, however, that storing delimited lists in a table is bad practice, and should be generally avoided. More about this can be read in [this famous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716).

Comment: Brilliant!  Checked the list about storing a string - none applies in this case, but definitely good to know. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @santa: it probably applies somehow... At least, you could be using a JSON array, which MySQL supports since version 5.7, and that is *a little* easier to manipulate than a string.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I'll put on my list for next version. This is not my code and is pretty old. Unfortunately I don't have time to go though all codebase and fix it now. Cheers.